# Post method does not return value of textarea

Tags: php, html, forms

Problem with the post method.
I have a html form where i use textarea as **disabled** and the value of the textarea comes from the database with the help of another page.

```
<textarea disabled name="sms" id="sms">
<?php echo $value; //Here the value of textarea and it shows on it?>  
</textarea>
```

My PHP code is--

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo $_POST['sms']; //This line prints nothing
}
```

My HTML code--

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<textarea disabled name="sms" id="sms"> 
<?php echo $value; //Here the value of textarea and it shows on it?>  
</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

When i want to validate it through values of it, I get empty.
Why this is happen???
Need help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabled fields are not posted to the server. Readonly fields are posted, so if you really need the contents of the field you could change it to be readonly instead of disabled.

e.g. instead of

```
<textarea name="sms" id="sms" disabled>
```

try

```
<textarea name="sms" id="sms" readonly>
```